# How to draw broken line wit CSS between two divs

Tags: css

Is there a way to draw with CSS broken line between two divs? Like in picture white line.
[image: broken line]

Comment: Which line are you talking about?

Comment: HI friend. White line what connects right block above with left block below

Comment: My be i am wrong naming it i do not know how to describe it in english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add center div between to two box.
Add `::before` and `::after` pseudo element to make zig line.
Adjust size according to your need.

```css
.top-box,
        .bottom-box {
            width: 300px;
            height: 150px;
            background-color: green;
            position: relative;

        }

        .top-box {
            margin-left: 200px;
            margin-bottom: 100px;
        }

        .bottom-box {
            margin-top: 100px;
        }

        .zig-line {
            width: 200px;
            height: 3px;
            margin-left: 150px;
            background-color: red;
            position: relative;
        }

        .zig-line::after,
        .zig-line::before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            width: 3px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;

        }

        .zig-line::before {
            left: 0;
        }

        .zig-line::after {
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }
```

```html
<div class="top-box" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
    <div class="zig-line"></div>
    <div class="bottom-box"></div>
```